# true/false linear questions

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine if each of the following statements is true or false. Do not need to justify answer.

1). A vector space may have finitely many distinct vectors in it.

2). Two finite-dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

3). The set of all linear combinations of any collection of vectors is a vector space.

4). A $(2n+1) \times (2n+1)$ real matrix needs not have any real eigenvalues.

5). Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvlaue of $A$ and $\mu$ be an eigenvalue of $B$. Then $\lambda + \mu$  is an eigenvalue of $A+B$.

So what I got was

1). True 
2). True
3). False
4). False
5). True

Am I right?

Comment: Are these all vector spaces over $\mathbb R$, or may they be over an arbitrary field? Can you provide the reasoning behind your ansers (1), (3), and (5)?

Comment: The only way to know if you are right or not is to come up with a justification for a true statement, or a counterexample for a false statement.  For example, what is your justification that the answer to 1) is true?  (The reason you are not asked to provide justification on your assignment/test is likely to save time, not because such justification is not needed to figure out the answer.)

Comment: ok no i got it its 1).T, 2)T, 3)T, 4).F, and 5).F